# JQuery noob: Show div on hover, click to toggle display

Tags: jquery, html, css

been playing with this for a few hours and can't figure it out.

[jsFiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/rfyxD/).

Basically I want this to show on hover, and click it to toggle whether it is displayed or not. I thought this was the way to do it with `display:block;`, but I can't get it to work.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you're using `$(this)` in the [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/), but that's the `<button>` (`#related-btn`) not the `<div>` (`#show-hide`), I think what you want is this:

```
$("#related-btn").hover(function() {
    $("#show-hide").toggle("slow");
}).click(function() {
    $("#show-hide").toggle();
});
```

[You can see an updated example here](http://jsfiddle.net/rfyxD/1/)

Or if you wanted it animated in both cases, this is a bit shorter:

```
$("#related-btn").bind('mouseenter mouseleave click', function() {
  $("#show-hide").toggle("slow");
});
```

Or...if you want not to toggle it, but have a click "pin" it, you can do that like this:

```
$("#related-btn").hover(function() {
  if(!$(this).data('pinned'))
    $("#show-hide").toggle("slow");
}).click(function() {
  $(this).data('pinned', !$(this).data('pinned'));
});
```

[You can see a demo of that here](http://jsfiddle.net/rfyxD/3/)

Comment: @Kyle - Welcome :) Is that the effect you're after?  I can adjust the example a bit if needed, just let me know if anything's not quite what you're wanting.

Comment: Thanks again, the basic functionality is there, but when you click it refires the function.. I think. (jq noob) I was after something more like hover: show, click(and mouseleave): stay shown, click again: hide.. if you understand?

Comment: @Kyle - Try the last example in the answer, there's a demo link, that's the code for "pinning it", for lack of a better term. - Here's a slightly modified version, hiding immediately when unpinning: http://jsfiddle.net/rfyxD/4/

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I was after! Thanks very much! I'd +1 again if I could.