# How to close my dropdown menu? (onclick)

Tags: html

I have tried my best to do it myself, but I haven't succeeded. I want the categories (archive, topic etc.) to be able to disappear on my phone when i'm clicking on it the second time. So basically when I click on "Archive" etc. I want it to close again after opening it when I click on it. How do I do that?

My codes:

```css
#primary_nav_wrap
{
 margin-top:0;
 width: 100%;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul
{
 list-style:none;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:2.5% 0 0 0;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul a
{
 display:block;
 color:#5e5e5e;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-size:70%;
 line-height:32px;
 padding:5px 15px;
 font-family:'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 3px;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li
{
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li.current-menu-item
{
 background:#FFF;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover
{
 background:none;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul
{
 display:none;
 position:absolute;
 top:100%;
 left:0;
 background:#fff;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li
{
 float:none;
 width:200px;

}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul a
{
 line-height:120%;
 padding:10px 15px;
 letter-spacing: 1px !important;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul ul
{
 top:0;
 left:100%
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul
{
 display:block
}
```

```html
<nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
<ul>
  <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">Topic</a></li>
  <li><a href="javscript:void(0);">Archive</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 1</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 4</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  
  
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928523/jquery-noob-show-div-on-hover-click-to-toggle-display

Comment: Indeed you need to use javascript to achieve that. Also you should be aware of the fact that a non-touch device handle [mouse events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) while a mobile (thus touch device) handle [touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events), which are quite different even if mobile browsers try their best to natively interpret these differences.

Comment: @BalvantAhir Thanks for replying. I know nothing about javascript but I tried adding two ID:s (from the link you sent) so it looks like this: `<li id="relatedProducts show-hide" class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">Topic</a></li>`. Apparently this is wrong since I didn't get the result I wanted. What should I do?